# Capacity of a capacitor fully charged vs half charged

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

I read in most places, when people ask "can I replace a 10v 10uf with 100v 10uf?" and everybody answers "it's the same".

Well... how can it be!?, I have a comparator circuit, that uses a little capacitor to set the "on time" of the circuit.

And it makes no sense, is not the same a 10v 10uf cap charged to 10 volts, that a 100v 10uf cap charged to 10 volts...

If I am correct, where can I find more info related to this? if I have a 100v 10uf cap charged to 10 volts, what is the real uF of that cap? when is 10v only?

Comment: They're not the same.  If you'd like to prove it, try putting a 10uf 10V cap where you need a 10uf 100V cap.

Comment: What is the difference between a 500ml glass half full of beer and a 250ml glass completely full of beer? Aside from the 500ml glass being twice as high capacity as necessary for the job (and thus more expensive and bigger than required) they both do the same job. Kanpai.

Comment: Well presumably with the 500ml glass, I've already got 250 ml of beer inside of me, that will make a difference :^)

Comment: ok I think I get it... so in the example: 2 capacitors, 10v 10uf 100v 10uf both charged to 10 volts, will have the same amount of energy, isn't?

Comment: Exactly. Just because the 100v capacitor could store more is irrelevant for the present operating point

Comment: One does need to be aware that it's generally unwise to use an electrolytic that is rated for a **much** higher voltage than the circuit will be operating with.  This is because electrolytics need some voltage across them to develop and maintain the insulating oxide layer, and the higher the cap voltage rating, the more voltage they tend to need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While practically there are a lot of differences between a 100V and a 10V capacitor (dialectic, size etc....)

An ideal (i.e., overlooking specifics of the dialectic differences and tolerance differences) 100V 10uF capacitor charged to 10V stores exactly the same amount of charge as a 10V 10uF capacitor.

Sure the 100V capacitor has the capability to store more (\$\frac{1}{2}CV^2\$ & \$Q=CV\$) but for that operating point the same charge exists in both.

Answer (score 1):

The capacitance is a function of the plate area and spacing, and also of the dielectric constant of the material between the plates.

The voltage rating is simply a function of the thickness of the dielectric and the intensity of the electric field that's required to cause it to break down.

The two are almost entirely unrelated. As long as the dielectric doesn't actually break down, the first statement holds, which means that the capacitance is constant, regardless of the actual charge or voltage on the capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of basic function, they are the same (as long as the voltage is within the rating of the 10V capacitor!)

In terms of long-term reliability - if they are both electrolytic capacitors - a voltage of 10V may not be enough to keep the 100V rated capacitor fully formed, and it may develop higher leakage current than the 10V capacitor.

Some electrolytic capacitor datasheets recommended maintaining a voltage of ideally 2/3 the rated voltage, and generally never less than 1/2, in order to maximise the useful life of the capacitor.

In practice I can't say I've ever seen failures I could attribute to violating this rule (other than zero or negative applied voltages!)

Answer (score 0):

The difference you see in the "on time" of your comparator circuit with different capacitors (of same value but different voltage ratings) can easily be due to the tolerances of the two parts.  If both are electrolytic capacitors the tolerances might be very large, (typical for an electrolytic).  So a timing circuit will likely not be reliable (or repeatable) when swapping out this type of capacitor. If a timing circuit needs to have a tight design tolerance then it should be made using a capacitor of high quality and a known tolerance.

As others stated, leakage currents could be very different in different voltage rated electrolytic capacitors.  Equal value capacitors of different material types can also have very different leakages.  For example electrolytics will typically leak much more then a polycarbonate capacitor of the same value. (The different leakages will make the capacitor seem to have a resistor across it, again making a timing circuit inaccurate.)

A few capacitor manufacturers provide charts in their specification documents that show the typical capacitance changes per a change in applied voltage.  These may only be provided if there actually is a significant change in value with the applied voltage.